# Why aren't my handlebars rendering after they change?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, render

I'm writing a node.js app that uses handlebars.js for templating. The initial rendering works, however when the handlebars change, it does not render the new ones. The initial rendering has the html show up in the console, however after the change I get `{{>index}}` in the innerHTML of the parent element. Here is my .hbs file:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="./img/MySpending.png"></a>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                        <ul id="navWrapper" class="nav">
                  {{#if settings.ISLOGIN}}
                    {{> loginNav}}
                  {{/if}}
                  {{#if settings.ISINDEX}}
                    {{> indexNav}}
                      {{/if}}
                </ul>
                </div>
            <div class='navbar_form pull-right'></div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="bodyWrapper" class="container" style="padding-top:60px;">
      {{#if settings.ISLOGIN}}
    {{> login}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if settings.ISINDEX}}
    {{> index}}
      {{/if}}
</div>
```

and here is my node code:

```
var islogin=true;
var isindex=false;

app.configure( function () {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
  app.set('ISLOGIN', islogin);
  app.set('ISINDEX', isindex);
  app.engine('hbs', hbs.express3({
    partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials'
  }));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
socket.on('login', function(data) {
    console.log('login');
    console.log(data);
    var checkUser= db.users.find(data, function(err, docs){
            if(err!==null || docs==null){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            var result=docs;
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    console.log(checkUser[0]);
    if(checkUser !== null) {
        user=checkUser[0];
        console.log(user);
        islogin=false;
        isindex=true;
        socket.emit('uploadList', checkUser.total);
    }
    else{ console.log('Log in invalid');}
});
```

I've also tried rendering the page again which crashes the program.  If anyone can even point me in the right direction as to how to fix this, it'd be greatly appreciated.